# NSDateFormatter no space to am/pm

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm using the following date formatter:

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter {
    static NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSString *format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MMM d h:mm a" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
        _dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];
    });
    return _dateFormatter;
}
```

An output example could be:

```
Mar 25, 2:05 PM
```

I need to change 1 thing:
no space between the hour and the am/pm

like this:

```
Mar 25, 2:05PM
```

Comment: Since you are using `dateFormatFromTemplate::options:locale:` it will always be translate to an acceptable format for the local. For example with a Dutch local the output will be something like: `2 maart 14:02`. You should remove `dateFormatFromTemplate::options:locale:` and just use a static date format, or accept that in other locals the date will present differently.

Comment: well using the templet is important to keep the right structure, so I prefer using it.

Comment: Then you will never get the `AM/PM` directly after the time, since that is not the correct presentation for the local that is used.

Comment: Why not simply remove the blank from the generated `format` string??

Comment: Note you should use "j" instead of "h" to support users who have set their device to use a 24 hour clock

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, it worked for me. (simply remove the space between mm and a)

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter {
static NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSString *format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MMM d h:mma" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    _dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];
});
return _dateFormatter;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I was using `DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "h:mma", options: 0, locale: Locale.current)!`, but that consistently added a space before my am/pm marker. Setting the `dateFormat` property directly with a string worked.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.amSymbol = "a"
formatter.pmSymbol = "p"
formatter.dateFormat = "h:mma"
let timeLabel = formatter.string(from: Date())
```

Comment: You should generally avoid using a fixed date format for user-visible strings as it will not respect differences between locales.

Comment: Yes. In my case I needed to use this format only for users in the US and I used a more dynamic format for all other locales.

Answer (score -1):

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter {
    static NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mmaaa"];
    });
    return _dateFormatter;
}
```

how about not to use template?
template's am/pm can't be sticked with minutes, weird

Comment: how about not to use template?

Comment: well using the templet is important to keep the right structure, so I prefer using it.

Comment: 'a', 'aa', 'aaa' and 'aaaa' are identical.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try like this

```
static NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSString *format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MMM d h:mm a" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    _dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];
});

NSString *date = [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSArray *aa = [date componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *combinedString = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[aa lastObject]] withString:[aa lastObject]];

NSLog(@"date : %@",combinedString);
```

Answer (score -1):

I create a simple yet not necessary the best solution. So I used my string to present it in a UILabel. So I sublclassed UILabel called ClockLabel and override setter for label's text. Here is the code:

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" am" withString:@"am"];
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" pm" withString:@"pm"];
    [super setText:text];
}
```

There must be some other soluton but I sticked to this one.